# An aggregator that can release when all records are processed, even with errors

Tags: spring-integration

I am building a [system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21088344/how-should-i-build-my-messages-in-spring-integration) with Spring Integration that processes all lines in a file as records. Because some of the String records are malformed I have multiple paths through the application via a `Splitter` and `Aggregator` combination (I'm building the `Aggregator` as we speak).

Further, some of the records are so malformed that they are effectively errors. However I have a requirement that all records must be processed therefore I must identify and log gross malformation errors separately and finish processing the file. In other words, I can not fail to process the file but instead must only log errors.

**Aggregator**
I intend to do achieve the goal of processing grossly malformed records by modifying the headers on the incoming message and passing the message on-ward to the `Aggregator` which can search for the existence of such a parameter. I'll effectively be hand coding in some error handling situations to my processors and aggregator.

My Release Strategy for the `Aggregator` will be when all messages are processed.

**Code Extract**
This code comes from a [blog entry](http://techiquest.blogspot.co.uk/2012/02/spring-integration-robust-splitter.html) by Matt Vickery. He constructs an entirely new message (using `MessageBuilder` and transferring headers) whereas I will just add something to the `Message` headers. He includes this code in a gateway which subsequently transfers the `Message` onto the `Aggregator`.

```java
public Message<AvsResponse> service(Message<AvsRequest> message) {

    Assert.notNull(message, MISSING_MANDATORY_ARG);
    Assert.notNull(message.getPayload(), MISSING_MANDATORY_ARG);

    MessageHeaders requestMessageHeaders = message.getHeaders();
    Message<AvsResponse> responseMessage = null;
    try {
        logger.debug("Entering AVS Gateway");
        responseMessage = avsGateway.send(message);
        if (responseMessage == null)
            responseMessage = buildNewResponse(requestMessageHeaders,
                    AvsResponseType.NULL_RESULT);
        logger.debug("Exited AVS Gateway");

        return responseMessage;
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        return buildNewResponse(responseMessage, requestMessageHeaders,
                AvsResponseType.EXCEPTION_RESULT, e);
    }
}
```

**Confusion (...at least, that which I know about)**
My questions are as follows:

- When I have such a release strategy (all messages processed), is that the best way to ensure all messages get through to the `Aggregator`?
- When using an `Aggregator` it seems like in practical cases, it would be very common to need access to the `Message` in some previous step, as opposed to just passing and processing simple POJOs. Would that be true or is there something I should be doing to simplify my design so I can avoid `Message`

I came across a [blog entry](http://techiquest.blogspot.co.uk/2012/02/spring-integration-robust-splitter.html) by Matt Vickery showing how he achieves what seems to be similar with an Aggregator. I'm using his work as a guide.

P.S. Per Artem Bilan's [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21089184/977087), I'm avoiding creating my own messages and letting SI turn them into `Messages`

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference for Aggregator if `payload` is valid or not. Its general purpose is to build a `List` (by default) of payloads to one Message. And it does it via some `sequenceDetails` from `MessageHeaders`. It is first.

If you use `Splitter`, it is responsible to enrich each produced Message with default `sequenceDetails`. So, if you have this configuration:

```
<splitter/>

<aggregator/>
```

And if your inbound payload is `List`, you end up with `List` after aggregator as well.

I assume, that your Splitter just produces String payloads from File lines.

Then you pass each Message to some service/transformer.

The result of that you may pass to the Aggregator.

But as you say some of payloads are not valid and your `processor` fails with an Exception.

So, how about just `try...catch` within that POJO method and return some payload with error indicator, e.g. simple String "Oops!".

As I described before: the result of POJO method will be pushed to `payload` of the Message by Framework. And what is magic, that `sequenceDetails` will be there in the `MessageHeaders` too.

I don't see reason to write some custom `ReleaseStrategy` for this task, or even any other Aggregator's strategies...

Let me know, what you don't understand.

**UPDATE**

To add some `error-indicator` to message headers and don't throw Exception, it really will be simpler to build a new Message from code, not via some `error-channel` flow:

```
try {
   return [GOOD_RESULT];
}
catch(Exception e) {
   return MessageBuilder.withPayload(payload).setHeader("ERROR", e.getMessage()).build();
}
```

But in this case you should use `<service-activator>` instead of `<transformer>`, because the last one doesn't copy headers from inbound Message. And you really need them - `setHeader` for aggregator.

Comment: Yes there is probably an easy way to add some indicator to determine if the file is in error. I would like to be able to add that setting to the message headers for records that have errors - maybe a header enricher or transformer or something

Comment: I also saw what you meant about the sequence headers on the aggregator - that is a default setting and not something I need to set myself. I have seen what you mean about SI converting POJOs into Messages behind the scenes however wanted to add something to the headers for message handling. I am having trouble accessing the original message from before the splitter though. I have logged another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21140718/977087) to show my problem getting beyond the Aggregator