# Message not available at end of Aggregator

Tags: spring-integration

I have [built](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21088344/how-should-i-build-my-messages-in-spring-integration) a Spring Integration application and transferred some messages around and [tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21134924/an-aggregator-that-can-release-when-all-records-are-processed-even-with-errors) to bring them together with an Aggregator. The application reaches the `Aggregator` but does not deliver exactly what I want specifically I do not release the group and move onto the next step.

My problem however is my aggregator doesn't have the original message (from before the `Splitter`). My aggregator is defined as follows

```xml
<int:aggregator input-channel="deirBoxProcessorToAggregatorChannel" 
                 ref="loggingAggregator" method="logAggregation"
                 output-channel="aggregatorToTransformer" 
                 expire-groups-upon-completion="true"/>
```

**And the code inside it is as follows..**

```java
public class LoggingAggregator {

private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(LoggingAggregator.class);

public void logAggregation(Message<File> message) {
    LOGGER.info("Have aggregated messsages. Will archive");
}
```

My message in that method, although it enters it, is always `null`.

#### Application Context/XML Spring Integration definition

```xml
<int:splitter input-channel="transformerToSplitterChannel" 
              ref="fileToMessageSplitter"
              output-channel="shippedSplitterToRouterChannel" 
              method="split" apply-sequence="true"/>

<!-- Now use a router to determine which Message builder these messages are sent onto -->
<int:router input-channel="shippedSplitterToRouterChannel" 
              ref="shippedToTypeRouter" />

<int:transformer input-channel="deirShippedBoxToTransformerChannel" 
               ref="shippedBoxTransformer" method="transform" output-
               channel="deirShippedTransformerToProcessorChannel"/>

<int:service-activator id="wellFormedShippedBoxProcess" 
                input-channel="deirShippedTransformerToProcessorChannel"
                output-channel="deirBoxProcessorToAggregatorChannel"
                ref="deirShippedFileProcessor" method="processBox" />

<int:service-activator id="malformedShippedBoxProcess"
                input-channel="deirMalformedShippedTransformerToProcessorChannel"
                output-channel="deirBoxProcessorToAggregatorChannel"
                ref="deirShippedFileProcessor" 
                method="processMalformedBox" />

<int:aggregator input-channel="deirBoxProcessorToAggregatorChannel" 
                ref="loggingAggregator" method="logAggregation"
                output-channel="aggregatorToTransformer" 
                expire-groups-upon-completion="true"/>

<int:transformer expression="headers.file_originalFile" 
                input-channel="aggregatorToTransformer"
                output-channel="transformerToArchiver" />

<int-file:outbound-channel-adapter id="deirArchiver" 
                channel="transformerToArchiver"
                directory="${dataexhange.springintg.refactor.archive.dir}"
                delete-source-files="true"/>
```

The process gets all the way to the Aggregator but does not seem to make it past to the `Transformer` or `OutboundChannelAdapter` archiver.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'll need to answer this question again properly... the answer and the way we found it (debugging) is nested through the messages in response to Artem's Answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `LoggingAggregator` isn't correct. I recommend you to read the [Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/3.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#aggregator).
Your `logAggregation` method should be like this:

```
public File logAggregation(List<String> lines) {
     LOGGER.info("Have aggregated messsages. Will archive");
     // Create Files from lines
     return file;
}
```

It is a main method of Aggregator: to get a list of objects and return one object.

Comment: I thought I had tried that however I notice also I use a transformer in the middle which you informed me does not transfer the headers meaning that the Sequence numbers would not exist on the message at the end

Comment: If you use the recommended approach of using POJOs instead of dealing with `Message` directly in the transformer, the framework will take of propagating the headers for you.

Comment: I use POJOs for everything now and have changed the argument type of LoggingAggregator. I initially used a Message<String> as an argument to the Splitter but now... definitely everything. When I debug I just keep looking back to the Splitter - don't even enter LoggingAggregator now

Comment: As far as you don't use any custom ReleasStrategy, can you debug `SequenceSizeReleaseStrategy`, if it return `true` for your case? Assume you lose sequence details from some message somewhere in your ustream flow...

Comment: Yes it returns canRelease == true

Comment: But when I'm in AbstractAggregatingMessageGroupProcessor, the attribute Group.complete == false

Comment: In AAMGP, headers on message include correlationId=ec5dc01a-1649-4e4b-b57a-b36edeae78ef, sequenceSize=1,id=8ee2d0e3-0bb1-4feb-8184-090adcd298b, and sequenceNumber=1. Correlation key matches - ec5dc01a-1649-4e4b-b57a-b36edeae78ef

Comment: his.aggregatePayloads(group, headers) in AbstractAggregatingMessageGroupProcessor, SI 2.2.6.Release - 
IllegalStateException: Failed to process message list. No converter found capable of converting from type 
com.t2.lhr.daos.ShippedBox to type 
java.lang.String

Comment: ShippedBox is something my transformers create. The splitter releases Strings. I'm not sure how or why that is happening

Comment: So, maybe your groupProcessor method should apply `List<ShippedBox>`?

Comment: But it does make sense that I should try that (`List<ShippedBox>`) and go from there. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Artem's answer is correct. I mistakenly thought that the objects I returned to the `aggregator` would be of type that were sent off by the `splitter`. You can follow how through debugging I came to that realisation in the comments to Artem's answer.

I did see somewhere, probably in the manual you can in fact return a type that can be  cast from the `channel` that feeds into the `aggregator`.

With that understanding I could in fact return Object, and cast back up to the required type for use in the logging object I would use either subsequent to or as part of the `aggregator`.